# Test class for before update trigger: How to log and view trigger debug messages?

Tags: apex, trigger

I've written a before update trigger and I am getting failures when I run my tests on it. In order to debug what's actually going on I would like to insert debug messages into my trigger, run my test, and view the output from those debug messages on the test results screen. How can I accomplish this?

Note: In the below trigger the issue lies in the line where I check if a record is closed. I've tried removing the comparison to check if the old record had a different status and I still get the same issue. For some reason it simply can't get the correct status/isclosed of the new record. It doesn't ever seem to see that a case has been updated to a "closed" status.

In the test method I create a new case with a status that defaults to an "open" state.
Then I update it with a status that corresponds to a "closed" state. My trigger fires on this update and doesn't see a closed state.

**Trigger**

```
    trigger CaseClosed on Case ( before update ) {

    Boolean hasOpenTasks;
    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

    /* 
        Find all of the cases that have had their statuses changed to "Closed"
        Then query for all open tasks on each case.

        Note 1: This trigger may need to be bulkified
    */
     for( Case record : Trigger.new ) {
        hasOpenTasks = false;
        if( record.IsClosed && !Trigger.oldMap.get( record.Id ).IsClosed ) {

            // Fetch and store the list of tasks associated with this case.
            taskList = [SELECT isClosed FROM task WHERE WhatId = :record.Id AND isClosed = true];
            // Check if there were any open tasks
            if( taskList.size() > 0 ) {
                 hasOpenTasks = true;
            }
             else {
                  // do nothing.
             }

             // If there were open tasks: append an error message to the case and revert it to the old case.
            if( hasOpenTasks ) {
                record.Status  = Trigger.oldMap.get( record.Id ).Status;
                record.addError('Sorry, this Case can\'t be closed because there are still open tasks.');
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Test Method**

```
  static testMethod void validateClosedCase() {
    // Test Case object
    Case c1 = new Case( Status = 'New' );

    // "Open Task"
    Task t1 = new Task( Status = 'In Progress', WhatId = c1.Id );

    // Insert a new case and an open task associated with it
    insert( c1 );
    insert( t1 );

    // update the case with a closed status.
    c1.Status = 'Closed';
    update( c1 );

    // Verify that case 1 has retained its original status and remains open
    Case c1_2 = [SELECT Status, isClosed FROM Case WHERE Id = :c1.Id];
    System.assertEquals( 'New', c1_2.Status );
    System.assertEquals( false, c1_2.isClosed );
  }
```

Comment: Here's an (easier to test) version of your trigger: `trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after update) {
    for(Case record: [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Tasks WHERE IsClosed = FALSE) FROM Case WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new AND IsClosed = TRUE])
        if(!Trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id).IsClosed && record.Tasks != null && !record.Tasks.IsEmpty())
            Trigger.newMap.get(record.Id).Status.addError('You cannot close a case with open tasks.');
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wondering how to use debug statements then this can be accomplished by simply using

system.debug('My debug statement');
You then need to go to your logs.  **Setup -> Logs -> Debug Logs** and then click 'New'.  Find yourself in the lookup field, and save.  You know will write your debug statements to the debug log and you can check them in the debug logs that are created when you run your code.

For your code, I would add a few debug statements prior to the check for the closed status to ensure the values are what they expect.

```
for( Case record : Trigger.new ) {
        hasOpenTasks = false;
        system.debug('Trigger.new is closed = ' + record.IsClosed);
        system.debug('Trigger.old is closed = ' + Trigger.oldMap.get( record.Id ).IsClosed);
        if( record.IsClosed && !Trigger.oldMap.get( record.Id ).IsClosed ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by having debug logs .

Monitoring>Debug Logs and setting your user you should be able to accomplish this .

http://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/code_viewing_log_details.htm

Answer (score 0):

For test methods, open the Developer Console (Your Name > Developer Console), then run the test. On the Logs tab, your test will appear after it runs, and you can open the log to find your debug messages. You may need to adjust your logging levels to try and weed out the messages you're not interested in.